# err:module:import_dll Library python34.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4\\QtCore.pyd") not found

Tags: python, pyqt4, wine

I've installed wine on Ubuntu, python2.7 and pyqt4 install. But when I try to import `pyqt4`, it shows the error :

```
john@Ubuntu-python:~/.wine$ wine python

Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit    (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

err:module:import_dll Library python34.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4\\QtCore.pyd") not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: Module not found.
```

Comment: Why are you using wine for python? Python comes pre-installed with Ubuntu.

Comment: The messages suggest that you're running Python 2.7, but you're loading a version of `QtCore` that is built for Python 3.4.

Comment: Blckknght's suggestion is solid.  Double check your version of PyQt, and make sure it is correct for your python version (2.7.13).  While checking that, also double check that you got the correct architecture (32-bit given the python output)